# How to process local programs in server CPU connected by SSH?

Tags: windows, ssh, remote

Processing local application in Remote high performance Server

I have a windows 8 Client desktop. Can I able to run my local programs in the CPU of the server computer via ssh connection?

Can anyone help to solve this?

Comment: What applications? What tasks are you looking to offload? Certain programs like Adobe Premiere Pro supports this (may not be through SSH though). What is the OS of the remote server?

Comment: as a general rule, only specially crafted programs will be able to do as you suggest. That said, you can connect to the server, from the server connect back to your PC, and execute a program, but unless its a portable or standalone program, it will not execute on the server correctly.

Comment: I want to run Matlab in my local PC but execution should be in server CPU/GPU. Server is running Linux platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can install an X server on your windows 8 client, then connect to the server and run the X client on the server.  THat way all your windows 8 client does is render the output, much like a thin client.